# How to check concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor thread execution results?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm trying to check the results of futures within this code:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_tests) as executor:
   result_list = executor.map(run_one_test_thread,
        ((i) for i in range(0, number_of_tests)))

   print("result_list: ", result_list)

   for result in result_list:
       print("Result ==========================>", result)
```

But it seems the code for printing the results is not reachable, and nothing is printed out.
printing result_list is giving:

> result_list:  <generator object Executor.map..result_iterator at 0x7fa968b4a888>

**Note**: I need to use `executor.map` and not `executor.submit` cause I need all threads to run in parallel (if that has an impact on the future results.)

Comment: Can you please clean up the code, ideally to the point of an [mcve]? Cleaning up the code myself results in an ``AttributeError``.

Comment: Note that ``map`` already returns the results, not the futures. A single loop of ``for result in executor.map(run_one_test_thread, range(0, number_of_tests))`` will already give you the results.

Comment: `Note: I need to use executor.map and not executor.submit cause I need all threads to run in parallel (if that has an impact on the future results.)` FYI executor.submit can also run threads in parallel.

Comment: @user56700, will look again into it. Anyway, I cleaned the code to use only map for now, and still not getting the results printed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. This code should not lack output, it should unmistakably crash with an exception ``TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()``. Note that just removing the ``print("len: ", len(result_list))`` should fix your program.

Comment: I found the `len()` issue earlier and removed it, code is updated. But still the same with no results printed. I have a question, if there will be an exception inside the `run_one_test_thread` method, then the code of printing the results will still be reachable?

Comment: @zbeedatm made an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the comment from @MisterMiyagi, may I suggest the following:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_tests) as executor:
    result_list = {executor.submit(run_one_test_thread, (i)) for i in range(0, number_of_tests)}
    for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(result_list):
        print(result.result())
```

It will also run everything in parallel. Results will come in random order, because whoever completes first is printed.

If you must use your own example, this is how to do it:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_tests) as executor:
   result_list = executor.map(run_one_test_thread,
        ((i) for i in range(0, number_of_tests)))

   print("result_list: ", result_list)

   for result in result_list:
       print("Result ==========================>", str(result))
```

Result:

```
result_list:  <generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x000001D5C03F8D60>
Result ==========================> 0
Result ==========================> 1
Result ==========================> 2
Result ==========================> 3
Result ==========================> 4
Result ==========================> 5
Result ==========================> 6
Result ==========================> 7
Result ==========================> 8
Result ==========================> 9
```

If you want to print the list:

`print("result_list: ", list(result_list))`

Result:

`result_list:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: Thanks. the `executor.submit` code worked for me, I had an exception inside the `run_one_test_thread` while cleaning, it seems it cause that symptom. I had to enhance your code to look like to catch the exception: `for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(result_list):
            try:
                print('-----------------------> resutl is: ', result.result())
            except Exception as e:
                print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> e is: ', e, type(e))`

Comment: I have something similar only im running a script that connects to multiple databases and runs a query and returns a dataframe. Id like to see progress as well. This is the threading query: ThreadPoolExecutor(len(full_server_list)) as executor: data = list(executor.map(sql.connect_to_sql(), full_server_list))  the sql query creates the connection and the sever list is the list of dbs. any ideas for how to do it?